# unable to hide html <input> in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx control on the aspx page with many controls and  an html  control .This is page HTML.

```
 <input id="AddCSMusicProdSearch" type="text" class="upper autocompleteProductId AddCSProdField" maxlength="25" style="width:40%;" />
```

I am trying to hide it in jquery (file linked in the aspx page) like this but it's still visible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    isIE6 = getIEVersionNumber() == 6;
    AmmendmentsForIE6();
    GetLookups();
    EnableDatePicker("txDatePicker");
    ResizePopupWidget();
    $("input.TimeField").mask("99:99:99");
    Enableautocomplete();
    EnableProductSettingsMenu();
    Showhide();
});

function Showhide() {   
       $("input#AddCSMusicProdSearch").addClass("hidden");
}
```

Comment: What about calling `.hide()` on your input you'd like to hide?

Comment: have you got a class called 'hidden'?

Comment: Note: `input#AddCSMusicProdSearch` is redundant as ids are unique and in a fast lookup. Just use `'#AddCSMusicProdSearch'`

Comment: have you run the debugger? maybe some error in any of the methods called breaks ?

Comment: Test your single function call by commenting out the other 8 lines before it. If any line fails the following lines will not run. Use a decent debugger (Chrome's F12 tools would do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Showhide function:

```
function Showhide() {  
       if ($("#AddCSMusicProdSearch:visible").length > 0)
            $("#AddCSMusicProdSearch").hide();
       else $("#AddCSMusicProdSearch").show();
}
```

or

```
function Showhide() {  
       var item = $("#AddCSMusicProdSearch");
       if (item.is(':visible'))
            item.hide();
       else item.show();
}
```

Comment: Note: `input#AddCSMusicProdSearch` is redundant as ids are unique and in a fast lookup. Just use `'#AddCSMusicProdSearch'`